# Linking tree node selection with another object (JPanel)

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make simple Setting GUI in Java (IDE Eclipse).

On the left is JTree (7 nodes), on the right is layeredPane with 7 panels (JPanel). I want to browse panels by simple clicking on nodes in JTree.

But how to do it? Especially i do not know how to link node with this appropriate Panel. I do not know how to tag it, or to assign it as an object to the node.

P.S
1. I do not know, if there is more efficient way to do it. 
2. I am new in Java, but not in programming. In Delphi there is no problem for me...

Thanx a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each TreeNode has index which you can use to link to your panel.
If you use MutableTreeNode (default implementation is DefaultMutableTreeNode) you can assign custom user object to each node - see JavaDoc for [MutableTreeNode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/MutableTreeNode.html#setUserObject%28java.lang.Object%29) and [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#getUserObject%28%29).

Comment: thanks a lot, i used index property of DefaultMutableTreeNode to determine, which panel should pop up...